# FIRInstallationsAPIService registeredInstallationWithInstallation:serverResponse:

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have implemented firebase SDK in my project. Now I am not able to see any crash report in firebase or any log but in Xcode Organizer, I am able to see this crash log:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1818c7c60 __exceptionPreprocess + 216 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1990f6ee4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1819986e8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140 (NSObject.m:147)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x18186154c ___forwarding___ + 1472 (NSForwarding.m:3577)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x18186075c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   ABCCore                         0x10895b748 __84-[FIRInstallationsAPIService registeredInstallationWithInstallation:serverResponse:]_block_invoke + 236
6   FBLPromises                     0x105bb5c38 __38+[FBLPromise(DoAdditions) onQueue:do:]_block_invoke + 36 (FBLPromise+Do.m:33)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x181587094 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1517)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x181588094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x181534d94 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1008 (inline_internal.h:2608)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x181534994 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 36 (queue.c:7770)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x181883014 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1795)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x1818404f8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2544 (CFRunLoop.c:3144)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x181853174 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
14  GraphicsServices                0x1a238e988 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2200)
15  UIKitCore                       0x1840567d8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1080 (UIApplication.m:3511)
16  UIKitCore                       0x183defc70 UIApplicationMain + 336 (UIApplication.m:5064)
17  ABC                         0x1048d80d4 main + 212 (main.swift:14)
18  dyld                            0x105b1c4d0 start + 444 (dyldMain.cpp:879)
```

This is happening in live application and very critical issue but I am not able to find the solution.

please help me out.

Also i have configured the firebase app in app delegate and also I have used `-ObjC` in `other linker Flags`

Thanks in advance.